# ExpressMapper - null to string.Empty

Tags: c#, express-mapper

I'm using ExpressMapper to map a Linq-To-Sql object to another object - but null values in my strings are causing issues.
Is there any way to convert these null values to `string.Empty` from within ExpressMapper?

E.g. Given the following classes:

```
class A
{
    string a = null;
}

class B
{
    string a;
}
```

When doing the conversion

```
B b = Mapper.Map<A, B>(new A(), new B());
```

I want to get `b.a == ""` not `b.a == null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [null-coalescing operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).

```
string a = "";
string b = null;

string c = a ?? "xyz"; //a is not null, so empty string is assigned to c
string d = b ?? "xyz"; //b is null, so "xyz" is assigned to d
```

This way you can simplify your call to this:

```
B b = Mapper.Map<A, B>(new A(), new B());
b.a = b.a ?? "";
//"" can be String.Empty, whichever you prefer for your code style.
```

Comment: I think that the null-coalescing operator was added C# 2. I'm certain he's using a newer version than that. :^)

Comment: @WillRay sorry I got it mixed up with the null conditional operator as far as when it was added

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured. No worries!

Comment: Thanks. It's certainly a possibility, but I was hoping to handle this inside ExpressMapper.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Member` function:

```
Mapper.Register<A,B>().Member(dest => dest.a, src => src.a == null ? string.Empty : src.a);
```

Comment: There's ~30 string vars that I want to treat in this way. If I have to do it member-by-member, it defeats the purpose of using the mapper in the first place.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible to do a custom map to run for all members

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was afraid of :( There doesn't appear to be any custom Converters either like in AutoMapper.